# I have to pass data value to controller using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

View File **product_grid**

```
 <div data_id="<?php echo $ro['category_id']; ?>" name="id" class="cbp-filter-item">
                                <?php echo $ro['category_name']; ?></div>

// try to post data using ajax                  

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.cbp-filter-item').click(function(){
            var id=$(this).attr('data_id');
        //  alert(data_id);
            jQuery.ajax({
                url:"<?=base_url()?>.index.php/Home/product_grid",
                type:'POST',
                data: {"id":id},
                success:function(data) {
                   alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hear i can pass the id to view but not work properly please help me to solved this problem

```
Controller ::
public function product_grid()
    {
        $id= $this->input->post('id');      
    }
```

Comment: you did everything correct, but what is your problem?? "pass data value to controller using ajax" means what??

Comment: TYPO:  url:"<?=base_url()?>.index.php/Home/product_grid",   typo  remove dot before index.php in ajax url

Comment: Does the ajax call reach your controller's action? because the URL "<?=base_url()?>.index.php/Home/product_grid" seems weird to me

Answer (score 3):

You must have to use `print` or `echo` otherwise there will be no response sent to client side so use `echo` like,

```
public function product_grid(){
     $id= $this->input->post('id');
     echo 'Data-Id is: '.$id;
}
```

And use the URL like,

```
url:"<?=base_url()?>index.php/Home/product_grid", // let there is / in the end of base_url()
```

AJAX Code,

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url:"<?=base_url()?>index.php/Home/product_grid",
   type:'POST',
   data: {id:id}, // no need of quotes to JSON Object keys
   success:function(data) {
       alert(data);
   }
});
```

Comment: Hello Rohan This is also not perform properly

Comment: Check in your browser's console for any errors and make sure that the AJAX request is made properly.

Comment: I get data properly but not send to controller

Comment: i Chcked and eroor alert can be run and display the html code. and not alert success function

Comment: I think it is Syntax error. Try `echo 'Data-Id is: '.$id;` in product_grid function.

Comment: Hello Rohan i can successfully passed data_id to controller but there is also display some html code plz help me...

Comment: Give me your working Code URL, otherwise you have to check your controller's code. I think you are getting some errors in PHP code. Enable Logs in config file and check it for any errors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44587319/i-am-trying-to-display-data-dynamically-id-sing-ajax link of My problem

Comment: This question differs from that and, You are showing HTML Content by loading view in same function.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.cbp-filter-item').click(function(){
            var id=$(this).attr('data_id');
        //  alert(data_id);
            jQuery.ajax({
                url:"<?=base_url()?>+index.php/Home/product_grid",
                type:'POST',
                data: {"id":id},
                success:function(data) {
                   alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>


url:"<?=base_url()?>+index.php/Home/product_grid"
```

Use + for concatination instead of .

Comment: Concatenation operator is used to add multiple strings in JS not in a single string.

Comment: Hey there. The `+` in the string will indeed not do what you think it will, you would need to close the string, put the plus, and reopen (`"<?=base_url()?>"+"index.php/Home/product_grid"`). However it's really not needed in this case.