# I am trying to display data dynamically id sing ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Controller:

In that i am used two table category and secound sub_category
In category I am fetched category name to display dynamically
In Sub_Category I am fetched image,price,title

```
 public function product_grid()
    {
        $id= $this->input->post('dataid');
        echo 'Data-Id is form controller: '.$id ; 
        $this->PizzaUp_User_model->getid($id);
        $data['res'] = $this->PizzaUp_User_model->select('category');
        $data['rs'] = $this->PizzaUp_User_model->get_cetegory('sub_category');

        $this->load->view('product_grid',$data);

    }
```

View File

```
<?php 
                        foreach ($res as $ro)
                        {
                    ?>
                    <div data-filter="<?php echo $ro['category_id']; ?>" data_id="<?php echo $ro['category_id']; ?>" name="id" class="cbp-filter-item button_id">
                                <?php echo $ro['category_name']; ?><div class="cbp-filter-counter"></div>
                    </div>
                    <?php 
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>  


            <div id="grid-container" class="cbp" >

                        <?php foreach ($rs as $row)
                              {
                         ?>

                            <div class="cbp-item <?php echo $ro['category_id']; ?>">
                            <div class="cbp-caption">
                                <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
                            <img src="<?php  echo base_url('image/category/'.$row['image']); ?>" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                            <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                                <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                                    <a href="more_get_id/<?php echo $row['sub_category_id'];?>" class="cbp-singlePage cbp-l-caption-buttonLeft">Add to cart</a>
                                    <a href="<?php  echo base_url('image/category/'.$row['image']); ?>" class="cbp-lightbox cbp-l-caption-buttonRight">view larger</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="cbp-l-grid-projects-title"><?php echo $row['category_name']; ?></div>
                    <div class="cbp-l-grid-projects-desc"><?php echo $row['sub_category_title']; ?></div>
                    <div class="cbp-l-grid-projects-price"><?php echo $row['R_price']; ?></div>

                </div>
                <?php 
                    } 
                ?>
```

fetch and pass id using Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".button_id").click(function(){
         var dataid=$(this).attr('data_id');
         $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo site_url(); ?>/Home/product_grid',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                dataid: dataid
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                 var error=xhr.responseText;
                 alert(error);
              } 
        });
    });
}); 
 </script>
```

Comment: what is the exact issue you are facing?

Comment: when i pass the data id to controller i fetched it properlly but with that some html code can also be display

Comment: What does `alert(data);` show?

Comment: alert (data); can be show the html text

Comment: Are you saying that you are sending the id from Ajax to the controller and then in return, you want to alert the HTML? Your question is very unclear. Please Edit and add what exactly you are doing and what result you expect. @VidhiPatel

Answer (score 1):

I dont know php but guess that your controller function missing parameter

```
 public function product_grid()
```

to

```
  public function product_grid($dataid)
```

Comment: try   type: "POST",
            data: {
                $dataid: dataid
            },